# Replace empty string with null values in RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hello i would like to convert empty string to 0 of my RDD.

I have read 20 files and they are in like this formation.

```
YEAR,MONTH,DAY,DAY_OF_WEEK,AIRLINE,FLIGHT_NUMBER,TAIL_NUMBER,ORIGIN_AIRPORT,DESTINATION_AIRPORT,SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE,DEPARTURE_TIME,DEPARTURE_DELAY,TAXI_OUT,WHEELS_OFF,SCHEDULED_TIME,ELAPSED_TIME,AIR_TIME,DISTANCE,WHEELS_ON,TAXI_IN,SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL,ARRIVAL_TIME,ARRIVAL_DELAY,DIVERTED,CANCELLED,CANCELLATION_REASON,AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY,SECURITY_DELAY,AIRLINE_DELAY,LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY,WEATHER_DELAY
2015,2,6,5,OO,6271,N937SW,FAR,DEN,1712,1701,-11,15,1716,123,117,95,627,1751,7,1815,1758,-17,0,0,,,,,,
2015,1,19,1,AA,1605,N496AA,DFW,ONT,1740,1744,4,15,1759,193,198,175,1188,1854,8,1853,1902,9,0,0,,,,,,
2015,3,8,7,NK,1068,N519NK,LAS,CLE,2220,2210,-10,12,2222,238,229,208,1824,450,9,518,459,-19,0,0,,,,,,
2015,9,21,1,AA,1094,N3EDAA,DFW,BOS,1155,1155,0,12,1207,223,206,190,1562,1617,4,1638,1621,-17,0,0,,,,,,
```

i would like to fill these empty strings with the number 0 to them

```
def import_parse_rdd(data):
    # create rdd
    rdd = sc.textFile(data)
    # remove the header 
    header = rdd.first()
    rdd = rdd.filter(lambda row: row != header) #filter out header
    # split by comma 
    split_rdd = rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(','))
    row_rdd = split_rdd.map(lambda line: Row(
                                             YEAR = int(line[0]),MONTH = int(line[1]),DAY = int(line[2]),DAY_OF_WEEK = int(line[3])
                                             ,AIRLINE = line[4],FLIGHT_NUMBER = int(line[5]),
                                             TAIL_NUMBER = line[6],ORIGIN_AIRPORT = line[7],DESTINATION_AIRPORT = line[8],
        SCHEDULED_DEPARTURE = line[9],DEPARTURE_TIME = line[10],DEPARTURE_DELAY = (line[11]),TAXI_OUT = (line[12]),
        WHEELS_OFF = line[13],SCHEDULED_TIME = line[14],ELAPSED_TIME = (line[15]),AIR_TIME = (line[16]),DISTANCE = (line[17]),WHEELS_ON = line[18],TAXI_IN = (line[19]),
        SCHEDULED_ARRIVAL = line[20],ARRIVAL_TIME = line[21],ARRIVAL_DELAY = line[22],DIVERTED = line[23],CANCELLED = line[24],CANCELLATION_REASON = line[25],AIR_SYSTEM_DELAY = line[26],
        SECURITY_DELAY = line[27],AIRLINE_DELAY = line[28],LATE_AIRCRAFT_DELAY = line[29],WEATHER_DELAY = line[30])
                           )
    return row_rdd
```

the above is the code i am running.

I am working with RDD ROW OBJECTS not a dataframe

Comment: the need is to convert empty strings to Null or Null values to 0 or an empty string?

Comment: convert empty strings to 0

Comment: ok, I'll propose you a syntax with regex_replace() that should do the job

Comment: thank you i would like it to be able to be incorporated within the function i have created

Comment: just wanted to comment i am specifically working with RDD

Answer (score 0):

You can use na.fill("0") to replace all nulls with "0" strings.

```
spark.read.csv("path/to/file").na.fill(value="0").show()
```

In case you need integers, you can change the schema to convert string columns to integers.

Comment: im also uing spark.textFile()

Comment: Is there a specific need to use textFile(), given that your file is actually a csv?

Comment: i think its because i need to upload and hence rdd row object was more suited

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your dataframe to apply the change to a column named 'col_name'

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F  
(...)  
.withColumn('col_name', F.regexp_replace('col_name', ' ', 0))
```

You could use this syntax directly in your code

Comment: I tested this in my Spark environment on an existing dataframe, as far as I know the syntax is the same (even if I'm not 100% sure to be honest)

Comment: where should i be placing this specific code in my function

Comment: i believe this only works on dataframe not on RDD

Comment: try to replace `WEATHER_DELAY = line[30]` with `WEATHER_DELAY = F.regexp_replace(line[30], ' ', 0)` (if it works, you'lll do the same for all columns. Another option is to make the update afterward (do not change your code but update the dataframe with this suggested syn,tax)

Comment: sorry if it actually not works on rdd :-/

Comment: what is the `F.`

Comment: I missed this line that you should add: `from pyspark.sql import functions as F ` (I updated my post accordingly)

Comment: I'm really sorry for that

Comment: I proposed you another solution, I will remove this one by deleting this post if you agree, as it will not be of any help

Answer (score 0):

You can add if-else condition while creating Row.

Let's consider `WEATHER_DELAY`.

```
row_rdd = split_rdd.map(lambda line: Row(#allothercols,
WEATHER_DELAY = 0 if "".__eq__(line[30]) else line[30])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please allow me another try for your problem, using [foreach()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.foreach.html#pyspark.RDD.foreach) method dedicated to rdd.

```py
def f(x) = x.replace(' ', 0)
(...)
row_rdd = row_rdd.foreach(f)   # to be added at the end of your script
```